# Find harmonic conjugate $v$ of $u(x,y)$ $=$ $e^{-2xy} \sin(x^2 - y^2) $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, partial-derivative, complex-integration, cauchy-riemann-equations

I hope someone can help me solve this problem, it is supplementary problem 2.53d from Schaum's book: *Schaum's Outline of Complex Variables, 2nd ed*.

I'm sure $u(x,y)$ is harmonic because I checked $\nabla^2u(x,y) = 0$.

Also, the Cauchy–Riemann equations are:

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}= −2ye^{−2xy}\sin(x^2−y^2)+2xe^{−2xy}\cos(x^2−y^2),$$

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}= −2xe^{−2xy}\sin(x^2−y^2)-2ye^{−2xy}\cos(x^2−y^2).$$

But when I integrate in order to find $v(x,y)$, I bump into integrals I can't solve, I tried integrating by parts but it seemed to me that it didn't work.

$$v = \int (-2ye^{-2xy} \sin(x^2-y^2) +2xe^{-2xy} \cos(x^2-y^2))dy.$$

Comment: Recognizing $x^2-y^2$ and $2xy$ as the real and imaginary part of $z^2$ leads to an educated guess for the solution.

Comment: See also the comment here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/215694/42969, or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1720918/42969.

Comment: Now that I've read your comment I think I know how to solve it, thank you very much. The links were really helpful.